# MSDeploy remote permissions needed for Windows 2003 Server / IIS 6

Tags: iis, deployment, permissions, iis-6, msdeploy

What are the permissions needed for running delegated deployments, using MSDeploy, targeting a Windows 2003 Server / IIS 6.0 ?

EDIT: this is a duplicate of ... [How to allow non-admin user to deploy web applications on IIS 6 using web deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438750/how-to-allow-non-admin-user-to-deploy-web-applications-on-iis-6-using-web-deploy)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow non-admin user to deploy web applications on IIS 6 using web deploy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438750/how-to-allow-non-admin-user-to-deploy-web-applications-on-iis-6-using-web-deploy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS6 can't be published to directly via Web Deploy, so you will need to use Web Deployment Agent.  Once you have setup the agent, the endpoint address should look something like this:

http://myserver/MsDeployAgentService

Note this is not an HTTPS address and does not explicitly specify a port. Also, the account publishing to this endpoint must have admin rights on the server (nasty, but necessary). Finally, make sure the "Web Deployment Agent Service" is actually running because it's not set to start automatically by default.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've got as far as getting the deployment via the agent, but I'm in the domain admin AD group. I was trying to find what the minimum permissions were so we could allow non-admin users to deploy. Has this improved in Win 2008 ?